# Have the before_create and after_create methods been deprecated in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password

  Rails.logger.info "xxy From outside" 
  def before_create
      Rails.logger.info "xxy From inside the before_create" 
  end
end
```

When calling `User.save` in a controller, my development log picks up `xxy From outside` but not `xxy From inside the before_create` so I would I be right in thinking that it's been deprecated?

If so, how can I call a model method before a save? Or been as `xxy From outside` was logged, does this mean all methods are automatically called when an instance of a model is saved?

Comment: `User.save` could be an update, in which case `before_create` is not called. Also, check pjammer's answer.

Answer (score 11):

[They are still there.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) You seem to be doing it wrong. This is the correct way:

```
# Define callback:
before_create :method_name

# and then:
def method_name
  Rails.logger.info "I am rad"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. You might be able to get the result you're looking for by overriding the before_create method (why would you ever do this?) as described in the [ActiveModel::Callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d22947e00820b4e011775cfb4ede109650db070/activemodel/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb%20ActiveModel%3a%3aCallbacks) source.

```
# First, extend ActiveModel::Callbacks from the class you are creating:
#
# class MyModel
# extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
# end
#
# Then define a list of methods that you want callbacks attached to:
#
# define_model_callbacks :create, :update
#
# This will provide all three standard callbacks (before, around and after)
# for both the <tt>:create</tt> and <tt>:update</tt> methods. To implement,
# you need to wrap the methods you want callbacks on in a block so that the
# callbacks get a chance to fire:
#
# def create
# run_callbacks :create do
# # Your create action methods here
# end
# end
#
# Then in your class, you can use the +before_create+, +after_create+ and
# +around_create+ methods, just as you would in an Active Record module.
#
# before_create :action_before_create
#
# def action_before_create
# # Your code here
# end
```

Answer (score 0):

They are still there. They just take a block instead of defining them as a method:

```
  Rails.logger.info "xxy From outside" 
  before_create do
    Rails.logger.info "xxy From inside the before_create" 
  end
```